# React TS spread operator

Tags: reactjs, typescript

My goal is to spread new item (query) to dataList. It is functional component.

```
const [dataList, setDataList] = useState([]);

  const transferData = (query: string) => {
    setDataList([...dataList, query]);
  };
```

Code is written in React Typescript and my editor is shouting:

```
Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<never[]>'.
  Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

Typescript is brand new feature for me, so dont know how to fix it and what does it mean. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
const [dataList, setDataList] = useState([]);
```

That's an empty array, and you haven't used any type parameters, so `dataList` is typed to be `Array<never>` (and `setDataList` can only accept the same sort of parameter: `Array<never>`).

Since you're going to be populating the array with strings, you need to tell TS that when you call `useState`:

```
const [dataList, setDataList] = useState<Array<string>>([]);
```

Comment: Thanks so much. And is there any shortand alternative for <Array<string>> in this case?

Comment: You can also use `string[]`, but I prefer `Array<string>` because it's more flexible with different array item types (and therefore more consistent if used across the entire codebase)